# post data to remote site using jquery and submlit default action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to post data to remote site and submit default action same time here's my code :

```
<form action="b.php" method="post" id="formID">
    <input type="text" name="client-nbr" id="client-nbr" /> <br>
    <input type="text" name="cs" id="cs" /> <br>
    <button id="my-button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">subscribe</button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mnd1yw9k/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this approach as opposed to trying to synchronize the default submit and an ajax submit in one user action:

```
 $(function(){
  $('#formID').submit(function(event){

      var cvs = $('#client-nbr').val();
      var cs = $('#cs').val();

            $.post('http://remotesite.com/azd/a.php', 
        { 
          a: cvs ,b: cs 
        },
        function(res){

        });

        $.post($('#formID').attr('action'), 
        { 
          a: cvs ,b: cs 
        },
        function(res){

        });

        event.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mnd1yw9k/3/

*Now open up the console, goto the network tab, clear it and then submit and watch your data goto two places at once*

Comment: yes its sent to two places at once but in remote site i've got this message (blocked:mixed-content) jquery.js:9172 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mywebsite/azd/a.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: you must either change your fiddle like to use the https protocol or stop using https on the endpoint url